# How can i search a non case sensitive word with Sql Server XQuery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery, contains

I'm using an Xml field in my Sql Server database table. I'm trying to search a word using the XQuery **contains** method but it seems to search **only** in case sensitive mode. The lower method isn't implemented on Sql Server XQuery implementation also.
¿Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2005, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

If you're using SQL Server 2008, you can use the upper-case function like this :

```
DECLARE @x xml = N'abcDEF!@4';
SELECT @x.value('fn:upper-case(/text()[1])', 'nvarchar(10)');
```

Here's a link on MSDN for the upper-case syntax and a couple search examples :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645590.aspx

Answer (score 0):

*[First](http://www.google.ru/search?complete=1&hl=en&newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=MdF&q=Sql+Server+contains+function+xquery+case-insensitive&btnG=%CF%EE%E8%F1%EA&lr=&aq=f&oq=)* link from google points to MSDN page:

[contains Function (XQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178026.aspx)

> In order to get case-insensitive
>   comparisons, the [upper-case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645590.aspx) or
>   lower-case functions can be used.